# CompositeTarget.Rendering in backgroundworker thread wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to run the animation on background worker thread. I am using key frame animation. I am unable to figure out how to fire the event CompositeTarget.Rendering from background worker thread which I think is created by UI thread.
My small piece of code.

```
BackgroundWorker bg;
public MainWindow()
    {
       bg = new BackgroundWorker();
        bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);

        bg.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bg.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }
    void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += StartAnimation;
    }
    private void StartAnimation(Object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }
```

The composite rendering event is not firing from background worker thread. How should I do  this.

Comment: Application code can't fire the CompositionTarget.Rendering event. It's done by the framework, as soon as you've attached a handler.

Comment: @Clemens How can I run this animation on background worker thread. Is there any other way round.

Comment: Not at all. See here: [Animation Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312(v=vs.110).aspx). As a note, what you're trying to do here is called "per-frame animation" on MSDN. "key frame animation" is something different.